# MOSS 2007 Custom List

Tags: 2007, custom-list

I am using MOSS 2007 on the goverment side and do not have Sharepoint Designer ability. I am trying to make a custom list.

I would want selected people who have access to see this list. How can I set that up?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a one-off list you can create the list easily using the SharePoint 2007 Web UI.

Please see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/create-a-list-HA010099248.aspx for an overview.

Then to restrict access you need to set permissions on the list.

Please see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-HA010021564.aspx?CTT=3 for guidance on this.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

open the list settings and add the users in the list permission area.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link this might help you

http://www.fpweb.net/support/microsoft-sharepoint/tutorials/sharepoint-2007/content/set-list-permissions/

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, create a group that has access to the list and then all you need to do is add the users to that group.

So if the user is in the group than they would have access to the list. If your not in the group then you cant see the list!

For full details and walkthough follow this microsoft guide:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customizing-user-access-to-folders-list-items-and-library-files-on-a-sharepoint-site-HA010254789.aspx#BMtypicalsteps

hope it helps :)